# Alternative solution for database synchronization

Tags: database, synchronization

There is a legacy database ISAM based.Cobol software that uses it doesnt even use transactions etc. It is a small company though ,only 20 people are using these programms most of the time there are no conflicts.(other are workers who dont touch PCs).
Everyday a cobol program exports fixed sized records for several things(stock, invoices,orders,sums ,suppliers ,etc) into a text file..

This text file is imported using an Access  macro into a jet database (mdb).Each textfile data has the current month. Every table exists 13 times  (Supplier1,Supplier2...) for each month and the other for the current month. So current month table is dropped and rebuilt by the macro. Then the whole database is zipped and uploaded to the webhost provider that runs a script to unzip the database and replace the old file.The asp pages also exist 13 times for each months and display grids with the data. (They are made with frontpage i guess).

Now i should add some extra functionallity but this system is a mess.Is there any other idea to synchronize easier?It is really hard as there are no real primary keys etc..

Comment: Sorry, but from this broad overview there's really no way anybody can give you a meaningful answer.  This sounds like a job for someone with mainframe, RDBMS, and web experience. This will probably involve several weeks of time just to understand all the implications.  If you don't have the necessary skills I suggest you find someone who does to help you get on the right track.  SO is definitely not the place to get help on this one.

Comment: I'm with @Jim-- what part of the system do you need to add functionality to? For general clean-up, you could start by setting up a reasonable database into which to import the daily text dump. Sounds like it wouldn't be too hard to add proper keys (combine existing keys with a field for the month+year), avoiding the 13x table replication and the need to add/drop every month. Whether that helps with your goals is anybody's guess.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers --

If it uses ISAM files then these MUST have a unique key for every record.

You need to specify more information about the platform and COBOL compiler used. I am guessing that this is one of Fujitsu, MicroFOcus or RM  COBOL. I don't know about RM but MicroFocus and Fujitsu support ODBC so the COBOL programs sould possiblly create the access DB directly rather than via extract files. (Do not even think of replacing the ISAM files with Access, this will cause deadlocks!).